# Compress-Archive creates invalid zip Files

Tags: powershell, compression

I want to zip a folder using the powershell cmdlet `Compress-Archive`, however I receive this message when trying to open the resulting archive with Explorer: [image: Error-Message]

This is how I use the cmdlet:

```
function Zip-Folder { #creates a .zip of the target folder 
    Write-Host  "Start Compressing $ProjectName at $Source"
    $compress = @{
        Path = $Source +'\*'
        CompressionLevel ="fastest"
        DestinationPath = ((get-item $Source).parent.FullName +"\"+$ProjectName+".zip")
    }    
    Compress-Archive @compress -Force
    Write-Host  "Finished Compressing $ProjectName"      
}
```

This works fine when using data types like .png, .py ,... but when i try to compress .net project folders or InTouch project folders, the error message appears.

I can open the archive with 7zip, however not with explorer and the Expand-Archive cmdlet.

Any ideas why this is not working?

Edit: The folder i want to compress has about 1gb and the .zip I get from the code has only 1mb. If i compress the folder manually using 7zip its 34 mb.

Comment: When you open the (invalid) archive with 7zip, does it show the full index of files/folders, or does it look like it only included _some_ of the files?

Comment: There is stuff missing.
Folders as well as files

Comment: Try running `Compress-Archive` with `-Verbose` - notice which file is the last one it adds to the archive - either that file (or its name) or the _next_ file in the directory will be causing the problem

Comment: Thank you, i managed to figure out what file was making troubles. thank you :)

Comment: That's great, I look forward to reading your answer! :)

Comment: I wonder why you didn't receive an error during creation of the .zip file. You don't set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Ignore'` in your script or pass `-ErrorAction Ignore`, do you?